# yarn pnp RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, plug-and-play, yarn-v3

I am creating a yarn Plug'n'Play workspace. But when I tried to use the `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` it gave me a "**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**" error. But I manually created the file and the sdks folder and resolved the issue.

But after that when I tried to install the **React app** it gave me the same error.

The command I used was: `yarn create react-app frontend --use-pnp`

[image]

Above is the response I am getting.

- Node: v18.12.0
- Yarn: v3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution to bypass the error

```
"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
```

1. Install the package `@yarnpkg/sdks` in the dev dependencies:

   `yarn add @yarnpkg/sdks --dev`
2. Then download the `sdks vscode` using the following command:

   `yarn sdks vscode`

Running both commands separately seems to resolve the problem from my side.